# rename list in data frame according to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda

it is necessary to create a column with the name according to their code. I have a dictionary, I'm trying to rename codes to titles. There are two conditions, because the code may not be in the dictionary, then you need to write the code, or if the code field is empty, then write the void.if there is only one code, everything works, if there are several codes, a problem arises

[image]
[image]

I tried to write a lambda function

```
missing_values = {}
dict_=dict_name
dict_fr=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_name, orient='index')
dict_fr.index=dict_fr.index.map(str)
for_ag_pivot['name_cod']=for_ag_pivot['cod_last'].apply(lambda x: ",".join(dict_fr[0].loc[str(x).split(',')].tolist() if x in dict_name.keys() else x))
```

Comment: The question is completely unclear. Maybe you would prefer to ask on [ru.so]? Otherwise, check out [ask] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). Either way, [please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`.get`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) in something like

```py
getSingle = lambda l: l[0] if isinstance(l,list) and len(l)==1 else l
getName = lambda x: ','.join([getSingle(dict_name.get(c,c)) for c in x.split(',')])
for_ag_pivot['name_cod'] = for_ag_pivot['cod_last'].apply(getName)
```

If `dict_name` only contains values that are single-item lists, you don't need `getSingle` and `getName` can just be <kbd>`lambda x: ','.join([dict_name.get(c,[c])[0] for c in x.split(',')])`</kbd>.